# How to create a function that is

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am not a programmer, I just a web designer with a bit of programmatic skills and I am asking for your help to learn a bit more about jquery/javascript.

I have a single function which is calling 2 different divs (test1 & test2)

```
myFunction ($("#test1"));
myFunction ($("#test2"));
```

I want to try to achieve instead something similar to

`myFunction ($("#test1")  $("#test2"));`

Because I want to try to use one call, to call multiple divs. As well my problem is that my ipotetical myFunction should look like this:

```
myFunction (param1, param2){ if(typeof param2 == "undefined"){param2 = $(window)}; // do something}
```

I have no idea on how to create a multiple call to a function for doing the same action but on different elements, and with the fact that I could have multiple parameters, it doesn't make it easy for me.

Any suggestion on how to do it? or some resource where I could read for? thx, in advance! :)

Comment: +1 At least you have tried something yourself!

Comment: @Anders, you are too kind. As web designer, you always try before, than google and than ask. The problem in being Italian and not English, and not even having studied programming (I am self thaught), I did have no idea on how to phrase the question. I should have just wonder more on Jquery website (sometimes I find it difficult to get what I want from the repository of the information, many interesting things are nested away)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myFunction($("#test1, #test2, #test3"));
```

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: I am such an idiot... I was trying myFunction ($("#test1", "#test2")); I feel ashamed to fall on the basic :( Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Another way, by making a [plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring):

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div class="blah">Another</div>
<div class="foo">And another</div>


$.fn.myFunc = function() {

    // loop over all matches
    this.each(function() {

        // do something with each match
        alert($(this).text());            
    });
    return this;
};

// call it on any set of elements like this
$("div").myFunc();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sbcvg/

Comment: This would be the preferred technique. Just use a valid selector function that matches all the divs you want to give it to.

Comment: what is .fn. of $.fn.myFunc? the definition to call a function? or something else?

Comment: That means you are "adding a new function property to the jQuery.fn object where the name of the property is the name of your plugin". Check out the link in my answer.

Comment: @karim79: I checked, but I didn't understand what was that element. +1 for have learnt a new thing :) [I only now noticed the first link, thx]

Comment: @Littlemad - It is the name of your plugin. So if you say `$.fn.makeItRed` then you would call it as `$("selector").makeItRed();`

Comment: a curiosity, how do you decide when it is better to use a plugin instead of a function? I tried to google function vs plugin jquery, or quickly look in StackOverflow and I didn't find anything that looked relevant